# Is there a way in css to select second last child?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Need to ensure browser compatibility as well (should work in IE8)

I came across - :nth-last-child(2)
But it is not browser compatible as it is a css3 selector.

Also I came across a tip to get 2nd, 3rd, 4th child as - td:first-child + td + td
But no way of reversing like
 td:last-child - td
 to get second last child.

I don't want to use jquery.
Is applying class to the second last element is only option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the conditions specified, applying `class` (or `id`) to the second last element is only option.

Comment: You could also apply an attribute as well.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS3 nth-last-child is probably the way to go, since support should become more and more common.

Failing this, you could simply add a CSS class to the element in the markup eg:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td class = "penultimate">...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Support for `:nth-last-child()` in 2022 is over 95%: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_nth-last-child

Answer (score 1):

### Only Because You Imply You Are Working with a Table

You are not clear on what you want to do to the second to last group, however, **only because your example is referring to table cells**, I offer this possible solution--using `<col />` styling.

It would require you to know the number of columns. [Here is an explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html). It has ***very severe limitations*** on what styles can be set (though it does work in IE8). [Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYxHL/2/), which has the following example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <col span="2"/>
    <col class="secondToLast"/>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.secondToLast {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not working with tables. Question was asked in general terms. I am having div elements in my applications.

Comment: @Ash--Are the number of `div` elements of unknown or an exceptionally large number of them? Are they interrupted by any other elements (`h2` tags, etc.)? rich.okelly has the "best" general answer, but there can sometimes be creative workarounds in CSS if the exact html structure is known better, which is why I am asking for more specifics about your structure.

Answer (score 1):

nth-last-child Syntax:

:nth-last-child(N) { }
N can be:

number - Any integer (1, 2, 10, etc.). 
This will match the child in that exact position, counting up from the bottom of the parent.
expression An algebraic expression of the form an+b to allow you to match on more complex combinations
odd - Matches every other child, starting with the last one.
even - Matches every other child, starting with the second to last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it is simple in **CSS**:

```
:nth-last-child(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**If `:nth-last-child(2)` is not working for you:**

You can count all children divs of parent:

```
var totalChildDivs = jQuery('.parent div').length;
```

And then target the second last child:

```
jQuery('.parent div')[totalChildDivs-1].css("background: red;");
```